# How do I get my Google Map to display in .NetCore web application?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

I'm follow the tutorial from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data. when I run my app I can see in my development tool that I get a 200 response from the server but my map does not display. I have no console errors.

I've got my API key from google cloud. I'm using the Maps JavaScript API. My billing is enabled. This is a clean .Net core web application.

index.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 2,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            });

            // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
            // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
            script.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }

// Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
// set of coordinates.
        window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
                var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

site.css

```
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

When I run the app on localhost or Azure my browser does not display a map. Why is my map not displaying?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue my creating a new controller action, and view. I then add the JavaScript and the HTML code to the newly created view and navigate to that controller action from the browser and google map displayed as expected.